# Creating and updating 3 index matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, physics, numerical-methods

I'm trying to create a three index matrix that contains 1 value (V) for every node of a numerical spatial mesh (xyz) (real world problem: the electrostatic potential created by finite-paralell- plates in a point of space). This matrix initially has to be filled with zeros except for some specific points (where the plates and space limits are) and then iteratively update the value at each node according to the following 7-point stencil method (j k and l indices of the x y z coordinates respectively):

V[j,k,l] = (V[j+1, k, l] + V[j-1, k, l] + V[j, k+1, l] + V[j, k-1, l] + V[j, k, l+1] +V[j, k, l-1])/6
(i. e., replace the value of a node with the average of the other 6 neighbouring nodes)

I've tried np.zeros and np.meshgrid but I think maybe I just simply have a serious conceptual and basic gap regarding arrays since nothing seems to do what I want. Any orientation would be really appreciated and sorry if I did not explain myself correctly. Here some code I've tried:

```
V1 = 10
V2 = -5
Mx = 101
My = 151
Mz = 301

V = np.zeros([Mx, My, Mz]).astype(int)
V[46, 51:101, 101:201] = V1   #the values of these nodes should stay fixed throughout iteration
V[56, 51:101, 101:201] = V2   #the values of these nodes should stay fixed throughout iteration
V[1,:,:] =V[100,:,:] =V[:,1,:] =V[:,150,:] =V[:,:,1] =V[:,:,300] = 0     #the values of these nodes should stay fixed throughout iteration

for j  in V:
    for k in j:
        for l in k:
            V[j, k, l] = (V[j+1, k, l] + V[j-1, k, l] + V[j, k+1, l] + V[j, k-1, l] + V[j, k, l+1] +V[j, k, l-1])/6
```

(Update after help from user kcw78)

Implementing the proposed code and trying to implement a while loop that keeps going until error falls below tolerance or the error in two consecutives cycles is the same. The statement of the assignment says more specifically:

"As many of these cycles will be completed as needed for the error to fall below a certain prescribed tolerance, rtol.  And what is a good measure of the error here?  We will use the maximum value of the local residual, defined as the  (absolute  value  of the) difference between the potential value at the central node and the arithmetic average of the other values in the stencil.  As a extra safeguard, we will also compare the errors of any two successive cycles and stop the relaxation if they become equal.  A better solution is no longer possible."

Now trying the code below, but not sure if it's trapped in an infinite while loop or just takes a lot of time since I have to stop it after 20 minutes without producing any output (also not sure if maybe I should use .all() instead of .any()):

```
import numpy as np

V1 = 10
V2 = -5
Mx = 101
My = 151
Mz = 301
rtol = 10**-2

V1_set = { (46,k,l) for k in range(51,101,1) for l in range(101,201,1) }
V2_set = { (56,k,l) for k in range(51,101,1) for l in range(101,201,1) }

V = np.zeros((Mx, My, Mz))
Vnew = np.copy(V)
V[46, 51:101, 101:201] = V1   
V[56, 51:101, 101:201] = V2   
V[1,:,:] =V[100,:,:] =V[:,1,:] =V[:,150,:] =V[:,:,1] =V[:,:,300] = 0



check_set = set().union(V1_set,V2_set)

error = np.zeros((Mx, My, Mz))
errornew = np.zeros((Mx, My, Mz))

while float(errornew.any()) < rtol or error.any() != errornew.any():
 V = Vnew
 error = errornew
 for j in range(1,V.shape[0]-1):
    for k in range(1,V.shape[1]-1):
        for l in range(1,V.shape[2]-1):
            if (j,k,l) not in check_set:
                Vnew[j, k, l] = (V[j+1, k, l] + V[j-1, k, l] + V[j, k+1, l] + V[j, k-1, l] + V[j, k, l+1] +V[j, k, l-1])/6
                errornew[j, k, l] = abs(Vnew[j, k, l]-V[j, k, l])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you will need 2 changes:

1. First you need additional variables to check the positions that are fixed thru the iteration. I added sets with `(j,k,l)` tuples to do this. So you can follow my logic, I initially created 3 sets; 1 each for these indices: 1) fixed V1 (`V1_set`), 2) fixed V2 (`V2_set`) and 3) boundary (`zero_set`), then union all 3 sets into a single set (called `check_set`). You could start with a single set and update as you add. Side note: your code has `V[1,:,:] = 0`, but I think you really want `V[0,:,:] = 0`. Let me know if I interpreted that incorrectly.
2. Second, you need to loop on the axis length in each direction(attributes are `V.shape[0], V.shape[1], V.shape[2]`). Inside the loop I check each `(i,j,k)` against `check_set`, and only calculate anew `V1[j, k, l]` value if it is NOT in the set.

See code below:

```
V1 = 10
V2 = -5
Mx = 101
My = 151
Mz = 301

V1_set = { (46,k,l) for k in range(51,101,1) for l in range(101,201,1) }
V2_set = { (56,k,l) for k in range(51,101,1) for l in range(101,201,1) }

zero_set = set()
zero_set.update( { (0,k,l) for k in range(My) for l in range(Mz) } )
zero_set.update( { (100,k,l) for k in range(My) for l in range(Mz) } )
zero_set.update( { (j,0,l) for j in range(Mx) for l in range(Mz) } )
zero_set.update( { (j,150,l) for j in range(Mx) for l in range(Mz) } )
zero_set.update( { (j,k,0) for j in range(Mx) for k in range(My) } )
zero_set.update( { (j,k,300) for j in range(Mx) for k in range(My) } )

check_set = set().union(V1_set,V2_set,zero_set)

V = np.zeros((Mx, My, Mz)).astype(int)
V[46, 51:101, 101:201] = V1   #the values of these nodes should stay fixed throughout iteration
V[56, 51:101, 101:201] = V2   #the values of these nodes should stay fixed throughout iteration
V[1,:,:] =V[100,:,:] =V[:,1,:] =V[:,150,:] =V[:,:,1] =V[:,:,300] = 0     #the values of these nodes should stay fixed throughout iteration

for j in range(V.shape[0]):
    for k in range(V.shape[1]):
        for l in range(V.shape[2]):
            if (j,k,l) not in check_set:
                V[j, k, l] = (V[j+1, k, l] + V[j-1, k, l] + V[j, k+1, l] + V[j, k-1, l] + V[j, k, l+1] +V[j, k, l-1])/6
```

After posting the solution above, it occurred to me that the ranges used in `zero_set` are intended to avoid the first/last (array boundary) indices. If so, there is no need for `zero_set`. You can handle this by modifying the range arguments as shown below:

```
check_set = set().union(V1_set,V2_set)
for j in range(1,V.shape[0]-1):
    for k in range(1,V.shape[1]-1):
        for l in range(1,V.shape[2]-1):
            if (j,k,l) not in check_set:
                V[j, k, l] = (V[j+1, k, l] + V[j-1, k, l] + V[j, k+1, l] + V[j, k-1, l] + V[j, k, l+1] +V[j, k, l-1])/6
```

Additional observations to consider:

- I noticed you created array **`V`** with `.astype(int)`. Are you sure
  that's what you want (and not floats)? In general, your calculations will not return integer values.
- The way your code is written, you are changing the values of
  `V[j,k,l]` as you go. So, you are using updated values of `V[j,k,l]`
  for `j,k,l` less than the current `j,k,l`, and previous `V[j,k,l]` values for `j,k,l` greater than the current `j,k,l`.
- Finally, I assume you are going to iterate thru this calculation until the change between 2 cycles is "acceptably small". If so, you need to have 2 copies of the array ("old" and "new") to take the difference. Take care to use `.copy()` when copying to create a new/different np.array object.

Comment: A million thanks for your help, and you are right: no `.astype(int)` and I have to loop until an acceptably small error. Updating original post with what I'm trying now.

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated answer based on new information and code added to initial post. You have at least 1 problem with your logic. The `if (j,k,l) not in check_set:` block skips over (j,k,l) values that you want to hold constant. As a result, you don't calculate `Vnew` at these points. That will cause problems calculation the change with each iteration (and will give the wrong result).
Also, I think you need `V = Vnew.copy()`. Otherwise, `V` and `Vnew` reference the same object.

Here is my simple approach to iterate with a hardcoded error tolerance.

```
check_set = set().union(V1_set,V2_set)
Vi = V.copy()
Vn = np.zeros((Mx, My, Mz))
diff = max(abs(V1), abs(V2))
i = 1
print('Start Cycle#',i,'; diff =',diff)
while diff > 0.25:
    for j in range(1,V.shape[0]-1):
        for k in range(1,V.shape[1]-1):
            for l in range(1,V.shape[2]-1):
                if (j,k,l) in check_set:
                    Vn[j, k, l] = Vi[j, k, l]
                else:
                    Vn[j, k, l] = (Vi[j+1, k, l] + Vi[j-1, k, l] + Vi[j, k+1, l] + Vi[j, k-1, l] + Vi[j, k, l+1] +Vi[j, k, l-1])/6      
      
    diff = max(abs(np.amax(Vn-Vi)), abs(np.amin(Vn-Vi)))
    print('Cycle#',i,'completed; diff =',diff)
    i += 1
    Vi = Vn.copy()
```

This implementation will "converge" in 10 iterations. However, this only checks the error between two successive cycles is less than a hard coded tolerance (similar to the second part of the desired error check).
I did NOT implement the first error check: *"use the maximum value of the local residual, defined as the (absolute value of the) difference between the potential value at the central node and the arithmetic average of the other values in the stencil."* I am not 100 % sure of the intent. Is the stencil the 6 points around `[j,k,l]`? If so, I think you need a similar calculation AFTER you calculate the new Vn values, something like this:

```
error[j, k, l] = abs(Vn[j, k, l] - (Vn[j+1, k, l] + Vn[j-1, k, l] + Vn[j, k+1, l] + Vn[j, k-1, l] + Vn[j, k, l+1] +Vn[j, k, l-1])/6 )
```